# Integrate $\int \frac{dx}{x \ln x}\, \mathrm{d}x$ using integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration, integration-by-parts

I know that the integral of $\int \frac{1}{x \ln x}\, \mathrm{d}x$ can easily be obtained through substitution for $u=\ln x$ with the result of $\ln \ln x+C$. My question is if this answer (or an equivalent one) can be obtained via integration by parts, and if not why?

I have tried the substitutions $u = \frac{1}{\ln x}$ and $dv = \frac{1}{x}\,dx$ which yeilds $$  \int \frac{1}{x \ln x} \, \mathrm{d}x = 1 + \int \frac{1}{x \ln x} \, \mathrm{d}x$$ which is no good.

Comment: I can't really be sure, but I really doubt that integration by parts will allow you to get to a step which allows you to forego the $u$ substitution above.

Answer (score 4):

So when you do indefinite integration by parts, this equation that you got should actually be

$$  \int \frac{1}{x \ln(x)} \mathrm{d}x = 1 + \int \frac{1}{x \ln(x)} \mathrm{d}x + C$$

or in other words $\int \frac{1}{x \ln(x)}$ represent a family of functions instead of just one function.

Now you might ask, what if you are doing a definite integral?

in the definite integral case, $$  \int^b_a \frac{1}{x \ln(x)} \mathrm{d}x = 1\bigg|^b_a + \int^b_a \frac{1}{x \ln(x)} \mathrm{d}x $$ 
$$  \int^b_a \frac{1}{x \ln(x)} \mathrm{d}x = (1 - 1) + \int^b_a \frac{1}{x \ln(x)} \mathrm{d}x $$ 
$$  \int^b_a \frac{1}{x \ln(x)} \mathrm{d}x =  \int^b_a \frac{1}{x \ln(x)} \mathrm{d}x $$

so nothing wrong there. To summarize you still want to use $u=ln(x)$ to solve the integral, but integration by parts didn't fail you.

Comment: Thanks! this still doesn't  quite answer the question of whether or not it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using integration by parts as follows

\begin{align}
I=\int \frac{1}{x \ln x}\,{d}x
= &\int {2\sqrt{\ln\ln x}}\ d(\sqrt{\ln\ln x})\\
=&\ 2\ln\ln x-(I+C)= \ln \ln x+C’
\end{align}
with $C’=-\frac C2$.

Comment: Nice method- you may as well define $-\frac{C}{2}$ as a constant on its own like $C’$.

Comment: @KStarGamer - suggestion taken, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Choose \begin{align}
v&=\color{red}{\frac1{\ln x}}\\
du&=\color{blue}{\frac{dx}{x}}
\end{align}
Thefore we have \begin{align}
dv&=\color{green}{-\frac{dx}{x\ln^2 x}}\\
u&=\color{orange}{\ln x}
\end{align}
Now using the recipe for integrations by part we get\begin{align}
\int \frac{dx}{x\ln x}&=\color{red}{\frac1{\ln x}}\times\color{orange}{\ln x}-\int \color{orange}{\ln x}\times \color{green}{(-\frac{dx}{x\ln^2 x})}\\
&=1+\int\frac{dx}{x\ln x}
\end{align}

Comment: So you've proved that $0 = 1$ :-)

Comment: @NickD No. Indefinite integrals can vary by constants. Two same indefinite integrals subtracted is equal to $C$, not necessarily $0$.

Comment: You noticed the :-), right?

Comment: @NickD this is indeed funny :-D, thanks for the messages. I think OP wished to spell out the derivations with which (s)he had primarily been unhappy; so I did them ...

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of ln (x) is 1/x so it's u'/u which is ln (ln(x))
if you want the easiest way to find the integral